# Why is there a metal piece in the wall itself?

Tags: walls

[image]
I’m drilling a hole into my outer wall and there is a random metal bit inside the wall. There are no studs or wires... what is it?
In the picture it is just the most bottom part of the hole ( it’s very hard to see srry )

Comment: it is probably there to stop you from drilling through electrical wires, or through some plumbing pipe ... or it is rebar if the wall is concrete

Comment: Since it’s a very minuscule piece, is it possible to make it how lower?

Comment: it looks like an old rusty  wedge bolt, but that doesn't match your text.

Comment: @Sturgis, ???? ... make what lower?

Comment: Metal part, can I just file it safetly?

Comment: @Sturgis, we can't tell you if it is safe to file, because we do not know what it is ... you need to figure out what it is first

Answer (score 1):

If its a concrete block home it could be the rebar used to tie the roof to the foundation or a tie strap. Then again I have dropped an entire saw into a wall and had to leave it because I couldn't get it out. Someone could have also run a ground or bonding strap depending on the construction. It up to you on whether or not to cut it without looking at the entire construction.